# Python 3 Evaluate Variable in String

Tags: python, python-3.x

Self admitted PHP coder turning to the Python side and my head hurts. I'm trying to do what I think would be simple. Read in a file (have that working) and then store each lines input into a variable then evaluate the string variable into an existing string of text.

Here's what I have:

```
with open('./users.txt') as users:
    for user in users:
        conn.request("GET", "/vmrest/users?query=(alias%2520is%2520{})".format(user), headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
```

All I want is the value in my user variable to be placed right at the end of the string right after "/vmrest/users?query=(alias%2520is%2520`user variable here`", headers)

Thanks

**EDIT**
Realized I didn't include what was happening sorry. Below is the feedback I get when executing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/http/client.py", line 885, in send
 self.sock.sendall(data)
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/ssl.py", line 886, in sendall
v = self.send(data[count:])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "amer-unity.py", line 12, in <module>
conn.request("GET", "/vmrest/users?query=(alias%2520is%2520{})".format(user), headers)
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1083, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/http/client.py", line 913, in _send_output
self.send(message_body)
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/http/client.py", line 889, in send
self.sock.sendall(d)
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/ssl.py", line 886, in sendall
v = self.send(data[count:])
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/ssl.py", line 856, in send
return self._sslobj.write(data)
File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/ssl.py", line 581, in write
return self._sslobj.write(data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: And your problem is ?

Comment: Your desired behavior is pretty clear, but I don't see any reason why your code shouldn't be working. What's the current behavior? (Side note: consider [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for sending web requests. It's *much* better than the Python standard lib.)

Comment: try printing out the formatted string and see what you get. it should be working. you'll also probably want to strip any surrounding whitespace from user (`user.strip()`)

Comment: So trying your request to just print the line:
>>> with open('./users.txt') as users:
...     for user in users:
...             print("GET", "/vmrest/users?query=(alias%2520is%2520{})".format(user), headers)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'headers' is not defined
>>>

Comment: It *looks* like the basic problem is that the `request` method is expecting a `bytes` instead of `str`, but that's a big guess on my part. A `str` is a text value, and unlike in Python 2.x, it can't be used as a byte sequence. I *really* recommend switching to `requests` and seeing if it just works; my suspicion is that it will sort of magically eliminate these kinds of problems.

Comment: I think I see the issue when it evaluates the variable it's dropping the closing ) at the end of the string.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm game for trying that however is it just import requests vs import http.client?

Comment: @rsaturns No, it wouldn't drop the closing parenthesis. *But* when you read a file line by line in Python, each line leaves the line separator (`\n` or `\r\n`) intact at the end. That's why acushner recommends `strip`ing the string. That could also be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as @acushner suggests, you should `strip` your line:

```
"/vmrest/users?query=(alias%2520is%2520{})".format(user.strip())
```

This will remove any leading or trailing whitespace from the `user` string. Keep in mind that in Python, when you read a file's lines, it includes the line terminator (probably `'\n'` since you're on *nix). This will make sure it gets removed.

You might also want to skip empty lines:

```
user = user.strip()
if user:
    conn.request("GET", "/vmrest/users?query=(alias%2520is%2520{})".format(user), headers)
    # ...
```

If that doesn't fix it, I highly recommend switching to [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). It's a simpler library for sending web requests and receiving responses. It generally "just works" without much fuss. It's third party, so you need to install it first:

```
pip install requests
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
import requests

# ... some other code ...

with open('./users.txt') as users:
    for user in users:
        user = user.strip()
        if user:
            res = requests.get("/vmrest/users?query=(alias%2520is%2520{})".format(user.strip()), headers=headers)
            data = res.text
```

Note that there is zero set up code for establishing a connection; you just call the module method. It has some additional niceties as well, like parsing JSON:

```
data = res.json()
```

Comment: Thank you this is now working and I can move on to my next challenges. You're definitely right requests is far superior to the basic http module. Not sure why Cisco uses that as their reference.

Comment: @rsaturns `requests` has gotten a lot of traction in the Python community, but there's probably still a lot of people who don't know about it. Cisco could also have written their docs before it existed, or they might be uncomfortable with telling people to install a third party library in their official docs. Lots of possible reasons. Glad I could help, though.